# How do we build a model with pyMC

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, naive-bayes, markov-chain, pymc

I am a newbie programmer with **pyMC**. I have a model given as following $$\rho=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$$ $$z=f(x,y)=\frac{c^3}{\log(c)+1}\frac{\log\rho}{\rho^2}+\frac{5.3}{r^2}\rho^{-3}$$ and I want to find the posterior for the given parameters $c$ and $r$ with their corresponding errors. Let's say I have a real data ,comes from observation for the given model and the data file contains $x$, $y$ and $z$ columns and the data-points are 5000 points.

If I consider **uniform** priors for $c$ and $r$. How could I build my model which computes in each ($x$,$y$) point the amount of $z$ and compares with the observed $z$?

Comment: It is not clear what your model really is: there are no evident random variables and $x$ and $y$ cannot be taken as "parameters" because they are part of your *data*.  Even if we assume that $z$ is supposed to be a random variable whose *expectation* (conditional on $x$ and $y$) equals $f(x,y)$, there are still no parameters in this model.  Please review the model you have been given and double-check whether you have accurately described it here.

Comment: @whuber, sorry it was a mistake. I have updated my question.

Comment: Thanks (+1). You can achieve some notational simplification by re-expressing the covariates $(x,y)$ in terms of $\xi=\log(\rho)/\rho^2$ and $\eta=\rho^{-3}$ where $\rho^2 = x^2+y^2$. It then becomes a weirdly-parameterized linear regression model with coefficients $c^3/(1+\log(c))$ and $5.3/r^2$.